# Set default application on Chromecast

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

Has anyone had any luck with persistence across power cycles?  I am looking to have an application that gets loaded *by default* when Chromecast starts up.

Answer (score 3):

This is not currently supported, however it has been requested on the Google Cast SDK site:
https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=62

Comment: Unfortunately as a Google employee [eloquently put it](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=62#c6): "This wont be be fixed."